# How i can use a eleven-digit number

Tags: c++, memory, numbers

I want to enter a eleven-digit number in my variable - number, but I think there's not so much memory. I tried to use *number and int *number = new int[100], but it's not working.

I also want to add name and lastname in my variable - name, but everytime I use space, it's stops working too.

How I can solve these problems?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct NOTE {
    string name;
    int number;
    int birthday[3];
};

int main()
{
    //int *tel = new int[100];
    //int *ptr = new int;
    NOTE arr[3];
    cout << "Please enter quality names and numbers or program stop working!";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "Man #" << i + 1 << "\n";
        cout << "Name: ";
        cin >> arr[i].name;
        cout << "Number: ";
        //*tel = arr[i].number;
        //cin >> *tel;
        cin >> arr[i].number;
        cout << "Year: ";
        cin >> arr[i].birthday[0];
        cout << "Month: ";
        cin >> arr[i].birthday[1];
        cout << "Day: ";
        cin >> arr[i].birthday[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost all modern C implementations use a 64-bit integer for the "long" type, which can handle 19-digit numbers. Or of course you can use strings if you don't need to do math with the numbers.

Comment: A telephone number probably should be a `std::string` anyways.

Comment: `int birthday[3];` you probably want to use year, month and day. Not an array.

Answer (score 3):

You are currently using a signed integer to hold your value.

```
int number;
```

A signed int can hold a maximum value of 2^31 (2,147,483,648‬), which is only 10 digits long.

```
unsigned int number;
```

An unsigned integer can hold 2^32 which is 4,294,967,296‬ (still 10 digits), which still isn't enough.

You can use a signed long, which is 64 bits in size and can hold a maximum of 2^63 (9,223,372,036,854,775,808), which is 19 digits long. That should suffice.

```
long number;
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm still have this problem. After I input digits, I getting Year, Mounth and Day by " " and program stops with exit code 0.

Comment: @Wanheda That means the program ended successfully.

Comment: I know, but it shoudn't be. I need to enter Year and others too.

Comment: Note that the name must not contain a space.

Comment: Also note that `long` is 32 bits on Visual Studio 2017 in x64 mode.

Comment: @drescherjm Visual Studio is not the only compiler with a 32bit `long`. But most compilers have `__int64` or `int64_t` available